# css style not working in second level of nested accordian

Tags: jquery, html, css

The following code represents a nested accordian object.  The styling for class `"cont"` works at the first level, but not at the second. Otherwise, the accordians operate the way they should. Any ideas why the second level styling isn't taking the class `"cont"` attributes? - thank you.

**HTML**

```
<div class="accbrowser">
<h3 class="cont">Occupancy</h3>
    <div>
        <div class="accbrowser">
            <h3 class="cont">Occupancy</h3>
            <div>
                Phase 3 - Log 1 </br>
                Phase 3 - Log 2 </br>
                Phase 3 - Log 3 </br>
                Phase 3 - Log 4 </br>
                Phase 3 - Log 1 </br>
                Phase 3 - Log 2 </br>
                Phase 3 - Log 3 </br>
                Phase 3 - Log 4 </br>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.accbrowser .ui-accordion-content{
    width:250px;
    background:rgba(255, 0, 0, 0); 
    padding-left:40px;
    color: #CCC;  
    font-size: 12px;  
    border:none;
} 

.cont {
    padding:0px;
    color:white; 
    border:none;
    background:transparent;
    height:10px;
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

where oh where is the css... thanks for the laugh.

update... Im thinking i need to somehow override the ".ui-state-default" class for this particular element.  These styles are overriding the "cont" class.

so sorry people... yes, its a Jquery accordion widget - I will attempt to post a fiddle this evening.

Comment: Where, oh where is the relevant CSS?

Comment: there is a high chance that overriding style happens, try using the rule `.accbrowser .cont` instead of just `.cont`

Comment: ".ui-state-default" ?? are you using any frameworks such as `jquery-ui`? if so, tag it in question. Can you provide a demo in something like a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: I definitely would recommend using Chrome's Developer Tools (CTRL+SHIFT+C) to see what is being inherited and from where.